# Javascript to ignore download prompt

Tags: javascript, html, download

I'm trying to set up some Javascript with a basic HTML page so that when something is attempted to be downloaded, it is done automatically with no prompt what-so-ever.

I have the Javascript linked in my HTML file, and the code from the Javascript file so far is as follows:

```
(function DL() {
var ie = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
    if(ie == true) {
        try {
            -a.prototype
            }
        catch(error) {
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            iframe.style.position = "absolute";
            iframe.style.top = "-999em";
            iframe.style.left = "-999em";
            iframe.id = "iframe";
            iframe.src = "http://www.9rays.net/products/spices.net/download/spicesdc.zip";
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        }
    }
}());
```

This doesn't need to work on anything else other than Internet Explorer.
The code was copied from another site which provided the source of the Javascript and so that is where the source of the iframe is from.

If anyone could provide assistance to set this up so that the file is downloaded automatically that would be fantastic!

Thanks in advance,
Chris.

Comment: im sorry but thats up to the browser and a security risk.

Comment: For security reasons, that will never be possible.

Comment: Okay I understand that. I'm just researching Drive-by Downloads and figured this is how they worked.
I'm working on a personal report about Drive-by Downloads and was looking to get a practical example working to deliver a certain exe file. 

With this in mind I'm guessing I would presumably need to attach this exe file to something else in order to hide the true purpose of it.